# Pyvista program won't show PyVista window on other OS

Tags: pyvista

I have a program that includes PyVista. I have generated .exe file and installation file with Inno Setup. The program installs and works fine with windows 11, but when trying to use it with Windows 10 it shuts down the moment when trying to open a PyVista window from a button in the program. So only the PyVista part of the program won't run.

Any ideas why?

I don't know what to try at all.

Comment: It would be useful to try to get an idea of why the window is crashing. Does the whole program crash? I there an error message? If you're running the program by double-clicking an icon (and thus not seeing the contents of a command prompt when the program ends): can you try running the program from `cmd`?

Comment: Hi, yes, the whole program just shuts down. I tried to open the program from cmd but there is no error message when pyvista shuts it down. Thanks for your effort!

Comment: Any chance that your code (that has the pyvista parts embedded) explicitly silences errors? It's somewhat unusual for a program to just silently stop (although I'm not sure how segfaults look on Windows).

Comment: Not sure. Atleast I have not handled any errors.